# how to create a dynamic data driven view without knowing the model type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a data driven application which imports large amounts of data from excel. However, I must first process the data bit and put it into EF models and then before committing to the database, render it all to the user in a bunch of tables to confirm. I am just wondering how I can render this easily in a view.

My model is basically `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` where the key is the model name, and the list is a list of the model objects. The reason it's object type is because each list will be of different type corresponding to its EF model. For example:

```
<"Model1", List<Model1>>, <"Model2", List<Model2>>, ...
```

The question is, how can I go through each object in the list where I don't know the type information, and render it field by field in a tabular format? If this is not possible, or not recommended in a strongly typed language, can you recommend a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via reflection:

```
@model Dictionary<string, List<object>>

@foreach (var table in Model)
{
    var properties = table.Value.First().GetType().GetProperties();
    <h4>@table.Key</h4>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var head in properties)
                {
                    <th>@head.Name</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in table.Value)
            {
                @:<tr>
                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                       <td>@property.GetValue(item)</td>
                    }
                @:</tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```